# why `/usr/include` is not in gcc default search path

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

As we all know,gcc will search some default dir when compiling targets,
I use `gcc -print-search-dirs` commnd and get this stuff:

```
install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/
programs: =/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/:/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

I have two questions about this:

1. What does `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/` mean, and why write like that?
2. Why `/usr/include` is not there?Doesn't gcc need to know where headfile is?

Comment: `..` means go back (up) one directory. As to why, I have no idea

Comment: The compiler doesn't search for *any* headers; the preprocessor takes care of them. Try `cpp -v`.

Answer (score 2):

So as to **question 1**, I found this in the [gcc mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2006-09/msg00199.html):

> Note that a/b/c/../../../x will only exist if a/b/c exists.

So your gcc will only search in `/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/` if `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/` exists.

Note that I've got similar search-dirs on arch, and the `/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/`-equivalent ones don't exist, so I'm not sure WHY they are even included, but Linux has a notoriously unstandardized directory structure, so perhaps it's important for other distros.

**Regarding 2**, from the man page:

> -print-search-dirs
>
> ```
>       Print the name of the configured installation directory and a list of program and library directories gcc searches---and don't do anything else.
>
>       This is useful when gcc prints the error message installation problem, cannot exec cpp0: No such file or directory.  To resolve this you either need to put cpp0 and the other
>        compiler components where gcc expects to find them, or you can set the environment variable GCC_EXEC_PREFIX to the directory where you installed them.  Don't forget the
>        trailing /.
> ```

This seems to print not the library paths, but rather the paths where gcc expects to find the components it calls to do it's work.

To find the paths the preprocessor searches, type

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
```

or

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
```

for the C preprocessor.

Comment: For question (1) you did not answer *"why write [it] like that"*. The path is most often relative for staging. Distros always build for staging; it is hit or miss what others software packagers do. Users rarely use relative paths. Also see `DESTDIR` in, for example, the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) or [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html).

Comment: @jww so you are saying that gcc, if installed in `/usr/local/...` instead of `/usr/...`, will then automatically find the 1) directory in `/usr/local/x86...`, too? Or that it is simply a holdover from `make install`ing gcc?